# XNA/XAML Animate border color on mouseover

Tags: xaml, animation, xna, storyboard, mouseover

I am making an image gallery in XNA and XAML. I need to have images with borders and on mouseover I want to change the border color. I tried different things which didn't work. When the IMAGE is mouseOvered the animation to change the border color should be triggered. Here is my code:

```
 <Border Name="myBorder"
            BorderThickness="5"
            BorderBrush="White"
            Width="100"
            Height="100"
            Padding="0"
            Margin="15"
            CornerRadius="10">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Image.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
            <Image Name="myImage1" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   Stretch="Fill" />
    </Border>
```

I also used EventTrigger and Storyboard with mo success. Is there someone who knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145700/change-style-of-surrounding-border-on-mouse-over) post

I should have removed the BorderBrush from the border definition. Now this works:

```
        <Border Name="myBorder"
            BorderThickness="5"
            Width="100"
            Height="100"
            Padding="0"
            Margin="15"
            CornerRadius="10">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Image.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Image.IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <Image Name="myImage1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill" />
    </Border>
```